# Как осуществить вывод в консоль НЕ ИЗ функции main()?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, консоль

Может быть надо передавать в функцию какую-то переменную потока вывода?

Comment: Повтор вопроса:  
http://hashcode.ru/questions/1811/c-hello-world

Comment: По-моему, не повтор. Кажется, ТС думает, что из функций нельзя просто так писать в stdout.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

void foo()
{
   std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;
}

void bar()
{
   printf( "bar" );
}

int main()
{
   foo();
   bar();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `conio.h`?

Comment: @VladD и что Вы имеете против танцев с бубном, жертв великому боги и conio.h? 
И Вы обшли молчанием printf...